# How to correctly 'install' wxWidgets on a Mac

Tags: c++, wxwidgets

I have been trying for a while to get the wxWidgets library working on my Mac, but I have been having tons of issues. I have tried both downloading the source and building it myself and using Homebrew.

I have gotten to the point where I can compile the following:

helloworld.hpp:

```cpp
#include <wx/wxprec.h>
#ifndef WX_PRECOMP
    #include <wx/wx.h>
#endif

class HelloWorldApp : public wxApp {
public:
    virtual bool OnInit();
};

DECLARE_APP(HelloWorldApp)
```

helloworld.cpp:

```cpp
#include "helloworld.hpp"


IMPLEMENT_APP(HelloWorldApp)

bool HelloWorldApp::OnInit() {
    wxFrame *frame = new wxFrame((wxFrame*) NULL, -1, _T("Hello wxWidgets World"));
    frame->CreateStatusBar();
    frame->SetStatusText(_T("Hello World"));
    frame->Show(true);
    SetTopWindow(frame);
    return true;
}
```

I use `` g++ helloworld.cpp `wx-config --cxxflags --libs` -o hello `` to compile it. This seems to work, and g++ doesn't report any errors or warnings.

However, as soon as I try to run it (`./hello`) I get a lot of errors, most of which go like:

```
objc[92442]: Class wxNSSomething is implemented in both
/usr/local/Cellar/wxmac/3.0.5.1_1/lib/something.dylib (0x10bd00c50)
and /usr/local/opt/wxmac/lib/something.dylib (0x10b329c50). One of the two
will be used. Which one is undefined.
```

and

```
./src/common/object.cpp(251): assert "classTable->Get(m_className) == NULL" 
failed in Register(): Class "wxSomething" already in RTTI table - 
have you used IMPLEMENT_DYNAMIC_CLASS() multiple times or linked some object file twice)?
```

...finally ending with a segmentation fault.

It seems to me that I have two versions installed in two different at the same time (hence the "Class is implemented in both ... and ..."). But if I uninstall the Hombrew one, it gets rid of things that cause the compilation to fail.

I've tried various potential fixes from the internet but none of them have worked.

I'm not really sure what to do here. Has anyone else experienced this before? What should I do to fix it?

My Mac is Intel and running MacOS 11.2.3.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

@scriptor6,

Get rid of homebrew install.

Get rid of the one you compiled

Download latest release of the library from wxwidgets.org/downloads.

Unpack it somewhere.

Do this

```
cd wxwidgets-3.1.4
mkdir buildOSX
cd buildOSX
../configure --enable-debug
make
cd samples/minimal
make
open minimal.app
```

If at any point you will get an error- let us know with the complete error message cut'n'pasted as it appeared

HTH.

Comment: It works!!!! I can't tell you how happy I am. I thnk I messed around too much with the configure options. The one thing I needed to do to get my original command to work was to copy wx-config to /usr/local/bin, but after that it compiles and runs flawlessly.

Comment: @scriptor6, you don't have to copy anything anywhere. In fact - you don't even have to install wxWidgets. Unless you want you users to compile your software. But that is different story and can be dealt with when you are done. All you do when you need to build your own application is: `cd <my_source_code> && g++ *.cpp -o <my_binary> /path/to/wx-config/wx-config --cxxflags --libs`. The reason you don't have to install it is because you may have multiple versions of the library and you may work with them at the same time.

Comment: Just make sure you use backticks around the wx-config command. So you don't have to run `make install` - you can just use the library from the place you compiled.

Comment: I'm assuming Xcode is required here to compile the library?

Comment: @Petri, either Xcode or Command-Line Tools. However it is easier with the latter as its simple `../configure --enable-debug && make -jN`. Also Xcode is not usually updated with the new files.

Comment: your steps work perfectly, however in my VS code project i get
```cannot open source file "../../../lib/vc_lib/msw/wx/setup.h" (dependency of "wx/wxprec.h")C/C++```

Comment: @SteliosSavva, forget about VSCode. Just install Xcode and build your software this way. Its very easy and straightforward. If you need to know how - just update here and I will explain.